# CreateFileMapping() - parameters of size

Tags: c++

I want to make a program, which will put some sentence in shared memory so another program will receive this massage. I made that, but I do not understand the 4th and 5th parameters of CreateFileMapping().

In my program I write 256 (5th parameter), but when I changed this to 1, the program still worked. I thought it should crash, because I assume dwMaximumSizeLow is the lowest size. When I put some value in 4th argument the program crashes. I thought this value should be higher the 5th, but I was wrong.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

const char name[256] = "Map1";
const char massage[256] = "Welcome in the world without rules";


int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    HANDLE  hMap;

    hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, (LPCTSTR)name);

    if (!hMap)
    {
        cout << "create error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char * data = (char*) MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, NULL,NULL);

    if (!data)
    {
        cout << "mapview error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    if (!(CopyMemory(data, massage, sizeof(char) * 256)) )
    {
        cout << "copy error" << endl;
    }

    cin.get();

    UnmapViewOfFile(hMap);
    CloseHandle(hMap);


    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain how the 4th and 5th parameters of CreateFileMapping() work?

Comment: Are you asking us to find Microsoft's documentation of this function for you? (this is easy to Google) Or an explanation of what certain parts of the documentation mean? (could you include quotes of the exact parts you couldn't understand? I could guess, but I'd probably guess wrong) I also don't understand how this code snippet is relevant to your question if you're only asking about how a single function works.

Comment: I am asking about 4th and 5th parameters of CreateFileMapping(), because I don't understand how it work. From documentation I thought, that dwMaximumSizeHigh is the highest size of data in shared memory and dwMaximumSizeLow is the lowest size of data. So I wanted to check how it works and I changed value in 5th parameters on 1 programme still worked. And I don't know why, because so it is the lowest size programme should crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explain very well the 4th and 5th parameters, `dwMaximumSizeHigh` and `dwMaximumSizeLow`.  They are however not the highest and the lowest possible size of the data, as you exprect.  They are the high order and the low order part of the same, each being a 32 bit part of the 64 bit size:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
!        dwMaximumSizeHigh          !            dwMaximumSizeLow       !
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

So if you put 256 in the both of these values,  your shared memory will be 256*4294967295+256 = 1 099 511 627 776 bytes ! That'll be 1099 GB.  Are you sure you have the capacity for that ?

**Why doesn't it crash if the size of the shared memory is too small ?**

When you reduce the size to 1, and write more bytes to the shared memory, you potentially corrupt memory.  It might remain unnoticed.

It doesn't crash, certainly because the segfaults are detected via the paging system, and a typical page on windows is 4Kb.  Your example message is too small for the paging system to notice that the requested address goes out of bounds.

Comment: The Microsoft documentation is not clear to me while this answer clears what high-order and low-order are.